# Knockout.js select options dynamic by id

Tags: model-view-controller, knockout.js

i am wondering if there is any possiblity to get the select options values from a function, which is invoked with a parameter.

for example:

my markup

```
<select data-bind="options: $root.getOptions('one', $data.ID), optionsCaption: '...', optionsText:'Txt', optionsValue:'ID'">
```

my js

```
    self.getSelectionData = function (type, param) {
    if (type == "one") {
        var idParam = new Object();
        idParam.id = param();
        $.getJSON('/MyController/MyGetAction', idParam, function (result) {
            var r = ko.mapping.fromJS(r);
            return r;
        });
    }
};
```

the "r" does contain the correct data, but no data is displayed in the select.

i tried several things but couldn't make it. any idea (or hint that i'm doing it wrong) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put `return` before `$.getJSON` because your `getSelectionData` function returns nothing instead of result of JSON request:

```
return $.getJSON('/MyController/MyGetAction', idParam, function (result) {
    var r = ko.mapping.fromJS(result);
    return r;
});
```

Or you can define `r` in `getSelectionData` function:

```
    self.getSelectionData = function (type, param) {
    if (type == "one") {
        var idParam = new Object();
        idParam.id = param();
        var r;
        $.getJSON('/MyController/MyGetAction', idParam, function (result) {
            r = ko.mapping.fromJS(result);
        });
        return r;
    }
};
```

Comment: yeah! thank you ! had to change the request to async false, that's propably not the best solution but ok for me now.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing an ajax call inside a function on your viewModel like this. It would probably make more sense to do the ajax call outside of your viewModel, and assign self.selectionData as an observable array, and then update it when your ajax call returns. That's more keeping in line with the knockout model.